# Single Quote in cpp cout

Tags: c++, cout

From page 72–73 of Programming: Principles and Practices using C++:

> We saw that we couldn’t directly add chars or compare a double to an int.
>   However, C++ provides an indirect way to do both. When needed, a char is
>   converted to an int and an int is converted to a double. For example:

```
char c = 'x'; 
int i1 = c; 
int i2 = 'x';
```

> Here both i1 and i2 get the value 120, which is the integer value of the
>   character 'x' in the most popular 8-bit character set, ASCII. This is a simple
>   and safe way of getting the numeric representation of a character. We call this
>   char-to-int conversion safe because no information is lost; that is, we can
>   copy the resulting int back into a char and get the original value:

```
char c2 = i1; 
cout << c << ' << i1 << ' << c2 << '\n';
```

> This will print x 120 x

I do not understand the single quote use here. When I try it, it prints [x540818464x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQY5l.jpg).

Comment: That must be a mistake either in your rewriting or in the book. If you copied it correctly, have you tried looking for an errata to see if it has been fixed by the author?

Comment: You probably want: `cout << c << ' ' << i1 << ' ' << c2 << '\n';`

Comment: Bjarne's books have quite a few typos, and not all of them make it into the errata. If you're reading a digital edition, those often gather new errors in the conversion, as well.

Comment: it's also available online, but on page 79: https://books.google.se/books?id=We21AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA41&dq=Programming:+Principles+and+Practices#v=snippet&q=safe%20conversions%20we%20saw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only explanation for that code is that the book is wrongly printed, or that's a blatant typo. The correct code should be

```
cout << c << ' ' << i1 << ' ' << c2 << '\n';
```

Answer (score 5):

`' << i1 << '` is a multicharacter literal, has type `int` and implementation-defined value.

You probably want: `cout << c << ' ' << i1 << ' ' << c2 << '\n';`

with regular character space.

Answer (score 3):

This really looks like a typo, we might safely speculate the author meant:

```
cout << c << ' ' << i1 << ' ' << c2 << '\n';
```

The incorrect code *does* compile though, but is meaningless:

```
cout << c << ' << i1 << ' << c2 << '\n';
```

Here, `' << i1 << '` (note single quote) is called a *multicharacter literal*, it has type `int` and implementation-defined value.

> From [`[lex.ccon]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.literal#lex.ccon-2):
>
> An ordinary character literal that contains more than one c-char is a
>   multicharacter literal. A multicharacter literal [...] is conditionally-supported, has type int, and
>   has an implementation-defined value.

Its usage is relativly rare, I personally have seen it as a way to define arbitrary constants, like in

```
enum state { wait = 'wait', start = 'start', /*...*/ };
```

Comment: I can see why that would be appealing for arbitrary constant values. Makes it harder to avoid including the header that defines them.

Comment: BTW, as they have implementation defined values, it might happen that `'wait' == 'start'` for some implementation...

Answer (score 1):

You should try this code (below). There is a typo that you, or that book made.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char c = 'x';
    int i1 = c;
    int i2 = 'x';
    char c2 = i1;
    std::cout << c << ' ' << i1 << ' ' << c2 << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By using single quotes, we can print ascii value.  So ascii value of the whole expression got printed.

Thanks i hope this will help